# MyEclipse 10 autocomplete not working

Tags: java, myeclipse

I have recently got MyEclipse 10 in work and the autocomplete feature has stopped working and I have no idea why.

Now the weird thing is, it works fine for the JSP project. In my work we have a online GUI which is created using JSP and runs on the TomCat server. But in any other project, the auto completions don't work. Not a single command will bring up the auto completion. If I try for example System. and try hitting control space, it says no completions for available. Has anyone had this problem before? And if how how on earth do I fix it, makes it rather difficult to program :P

Thanks in advance for any help

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Turn on Autocompletion by going to Java->Editor->Content Assist->Advanced. Ensure that Java Proposals is selected.

[image: Eclipse Window Preferences]

Comment: Thanks, I was unaware you could turn off Auto Complete in MyEclipse. I do not understand why it was turned off, would have thought my default it would surely be on

Comment: I'd faced this issue a month ago - Eclipse suddenly turned auto-completion off. It warned me when it turned it off - but didn't explain why.

Answer (score 3):

Java auto-complete in MyEclipse and Eclipse will sometimes take too long to show proposals; this could be caused by a variety of reasons ranging from a system under severe load at the point at which the auto-complete was invoked to a glitch or an unusually large classpath.

Since a delay here locks your UI, Eclipse will detect this, break the auto-complete request and inform you that it took too long to complete via a dialog. It also gives you the option to turn off the auto-complete processor which took too long; if you weren't paying attention, you may have turned it off through this dialog (this happened to me a few times in my early Eclispe days).

This simply explains why it may have suddenly turned off, you would need to turn it back on using Hippo's suggestion above.

Comment: I was unaware that you could even turn it off until I encountered this problem. I may have done as you said and turned it off by accident. Its very strange using eclipse without auto-complete