# Auto Activation in Eclipse

Tags: java, myeclipse

Here is a problem with MyEclipse. While I input "." after some variables e.g. `list.size()`, in the past Eclipse automatically suggested me all possible methods and options. But now this function is not working. And also I have already enabled the Auto Activation option in Eclipse preferences.
MyEclipse Version = 10.7.1

If someone knows about this problem, please suggest me how to solve.

Comment: Did you try these suggestions http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8729796/myeclipse-10-autocomplete-not-working?

Comment: If you verify the settings as suggested by ile and they look correct, can you post a sample of a test class you've created in Eclipse that is displaying this behavior, including where you are expecting the Auto Activation option?

Comment: Yeah i opened the link that you suggested me, I tuned on Autocompletion by going to Java->Editor->Content Assist->Advanced. and selected Java Proposals. Problem has been solved. Thanks very much!

Answer (score 2):

Check the value of the content assist trigger.

[image: Auto Activation Trigger]

Answer (score 0):

Since I do not have all your Eclipse setting, I would suggest going to the `Preference` -> `Java`->`Editor`->`Content Assist` and click `Restoring Defaults`.